# Are there classes for that FO-model checking is FPT on hypergraphs?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, lo.logic, hypergraphs, first-order-logic

For graphs, there are many classes that admit FPT-algorithms for model checking of first order logic, e.g. the class of nowhere dense graphs by Grohe et. al.

Are there similar results for ($k$-uniform) hypergraphs, when viewing a hypergraph as as structure equipped with a $k$-ary relation symbol $E$? If so, can you point me to the according literature?

Comment: Such FPT results for FO model-checking on classes of graphs can be lifted to classes of finite relational structures, by interpreting each structure into a (possibly coloured) graph.

Comment: @Sylvain Care to elaborate on that? What properties does a class of finite relational structures need to have so that I can encode this class as some class of graphs for which the FO MC is in FPT? References?

Comment: Because it's sort of a folklore argument, most papers do not include an explanation.  Here is one place I remember it being explicit: Section 4.3 of Alexandre Vigny's PhD thesis (https://hal.inria.fr/tel-01963540/document).

Comment: @Sylvain Why not post that comment as an answer? It answers precisely the question that the OP had.